# Update column with random links from a list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table named users (25k records)

Inside I have a field named "Avatar"

I need to update this field assigning one random url from list

list urls:

```
http://myserver.com/img/1.png
http://myserver.com/img/2.png
http://myserver.com/img/3.png
http://myserver.com/img/4.png
http://myserver.com/img/5.png
http://myserver.com/img/6.png
http://myserver.com/img/7.png
http://myserver.com/img/8.png
http://myserver.com/img/9.png
http://myserver.com/img/10.png
http://myserver.com/img/11.png
http://myserver.com/img/12.png
http://myserver.com/img/13.png
http://myserver.com/img/14.png
http://myserver.com/img/15.png
```

I have this code:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE=VALUE+ROUND(1+RAND()*4);
```

how can I adapt this query?

Comment: What is list url,an array a column?Be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
UPDATE users
   SET avatar = CONCAT('http://myserver.com/img/', FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 15), '.png');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bea5e6/2)** demo

---

Although I'd suggest to store just the integer part, if you need to store it at all,

```sql
UPDATE users
   SET avatar = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 15);

SELECT id, CONCAT('http://myserver.com/img/', avatar, '.png') avatar
  FROM users;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b206/1)** demo

and then construct an avatar url on the fly when you select your data or better yet do it in your client code (getting domain name and a path from some sort of setting)

```sql
SELECT id, CONCAT('http://myserver.com/img/', FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 15), '.png') avatar
  FROM users;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e08d/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @peterm is good if your images follow a nice pattern, but you can also pick a random string from a list:

```
SELECT ELT(ROUND(0.5+RAND()*15), 
 'http://myserver.com/img/1.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/2.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/3.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/4.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/5.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/6.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/7.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/8.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/9.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/10.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/11.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/12.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/13.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/14.png',
 'http://myserver.com/img/15.png') AS avatar;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

To update the table, you can use the same `ELT()` expression in an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET AVATAR=ELT(...);
```